# How to add for this script error info?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Please help me. How to add for this script error info (eg no page)? I would like to view this information in loader.

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
    var container_div = ''; 
    var content_div = ''; 
    return {
        getContent : function(url){
            $(container_div).animate({opacity:0}, //Turn the opacity to 0
                    function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax                        
                        $(container_div).find("#loading").show();
                        $(container_div).load(url+" "+content_div, //only loads the selected portion
                        function(){                        
                           $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); //and finally bring back the opacity back to 1
                           $(container_div).find("#loading").hide();                           
                    }
                );        
            });
        },
        ajaxify_links: function(elements){
            $(elements).click(function(){
                $('#loading').show();
                AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);
                return false; //prevents the link from beign followed
            });
        },
        init: function(params){ //sets the initial parameters
            container_div = params.containerDiv; 
            content_div = params.contentDiv;
            return this; //returns the object in order to make it chainable
        }
    }
}()

/* Ajax Content Loading Controls */
$(function(){
        AjaxContent.init({containerDiv:".content_background",contentDiv:"#text"}).ajaxify_links("#nav a");
    });`
```

Answer (score 2):

look into http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/.. first, add an element to which you'll add your error message content

```
<div id="errors"></div>
```

then add some javascript to catch Ajax Errors and write to this div

```
$( "#errors" ).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
  $(this).text("your error message");
});
```

or if you don't want to bind the `ajaxError` event to a div, use this code:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    console.log("your error message");
});
```

or to use your code exactly, try this:

```
var AjaxContent = function(){
    var container_div = ''; 
    var content_div = ''; 
    return {
        getContent : function(url){
            $(container_div).animate({opacity:0}, //Turn the opacity to 0
                    function(){ // the callback, loads the content with ajax                        
                        $(container_div).find("#loading").show();
                        $(container_div).load(url+" "+content_div, //only loads the selected portion
                        function(){                        
                           $(container_div).animate({opacity:1}); //and finally bring back the opacity back to 1
                           $(container_div).find("#loading").hide();                           
                    }
                );        
            });
        },
        ajaxify_links: function(elements){
            $(elements).click(function(){
                $('#loading').show();
                AjaxContent.getContent(this.href);
                return false; //prevents the link from beign followed
            });
        },
        init: function(params){ //sets the initial parameters
            container_div = params.containerDiv; 
            content_div = params.contentDiv;
            return this; //returns the object in order to make it chainable
        }
    }
}()

/* Ajax Content Loading Controls */
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError(function(e, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.log("your error message");
    });
   AjaxContent.init({containerDiv:".content_background",contentDiv:"#text"}).ajaxify_links("#nav a");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. But this can not be put together and turn on error loading without adding a div?

Comment: you don't need to add a separate div, you can bind the `ajaxError` event to any DOM element you wish. I'll edit the answer to show you.

Comment: Can you add me to the code above, I do not really know how to do it.

Comment: I added, and after clicking on that page there is loading ... disappears and the error does not appear.

Comment: The same. The error does not occur. Loading disappears and nothing more. If it can be done so that the loading would disappear and appear in his place, no page text will be great.

Comment: are you checking the browser console? The `console.log` command i used in the answer writes to the javascript console. If you prefer, change `console.log` to `alert` to get a modal popup.